# What is causing these fields to be validated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-ajax

I have a number of fields within my form. When they are submitted (by ajax) the drop down and one of the the text fields go red to indicate they are empty.

No other fields are validated in this way and I haven't set up any validation rules in the ViewModel.

Does anyone know what is causing this?
Thanks.

**Update: It would appear that this validation happens on all numeric fields (i.e. where a long is submitted)**

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Comment: Does the HTML have the `required="true"` attribute? It may just be the browser doing what the HTML tells  it do to

Comment: no, they don't have that

Comment: see update, it looks like every field that stores a long is treated as required by default

Comment: If your form field has a `type=number` or similar then it's probably the browser chipping in and forcing validation. Also, check you don't have any plugins running in the browser doing the same kind of thing. You'll see a similar thing with email, etc. On mobile it will display a specific keyboard for the input.

Answer (score 1):

`int` field should be type `number` in html, and it should submit 0, if it is text it submits `null` value, `null` cannot be able to bind with `int`, thats the reason you are getting validation error message

You need to make it as nullable int (i.e. `int?`) if you need to save null value;

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, the non nullable fields such as int, long, double, bool etc will have the required validation by default, even if they are not decorated with the required attribute.

To allow null values and remove the validation you can change the field types as nullable e.g. long?, int?, bool? etc